# OpenCV Unmanaged DLLs not found asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, opencv, unmanaged, emgucv

We are building a web application (C# .NET) that uses unmanaged libraries in the form of the Emgu opencv wrapper. We are forcing the build to be in 32-bit (x86), and we are using the 32-bit version of Emgu.

All this works nice on local builds, but when being published to our webserver the openCV Dll(s) fail to load:

```
System.DllNotFoundException
Unable to load DLL 'opencv_core240': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)

System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'Emgu.CV.CvInvoke' threw an exception. ---> System.DllNotFoundException: Unable to load DLL 'opencv_core240': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)
   at Emgu.CV.CvInvoke.cvRedirectError(CvErrorCallback errorHandler, IntPtr userdata, IntPtr prevUserdata)
   at Emgu.CV.CvInvoke..cctor()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Emgu.CV.CvInvoke.cvCreateImageHeader(Size size, IPL_DEPTH depth, Int32 channels)
   at Emgu.CV.Image`2.AllocateData(Int32 rows, Int32 cols, Int32 numberOfChannels)
   at Emgu.CV.Image`2.set_Bitmap(Bitmap value)
   at Emgu.CV.Image`2..ctor(Bitmap bmp)
```

I tried the following things that I've found on stackoverflow and other sources:

- Put the unmanaged Opencv Dll's in a seperate directory and put the
  path to this directory in the path environment variable, and restart
  the webservice.
- Tested whether the server config allows for unmanaged    code
  execution (yes)
- Putting the unmanaged Opencv Dll's in system32\inetsrv and
  SysWOW64\inetsrv directories
- Puting the unmanaged Opencv Dll's in a subdirectory 'x86' in the
  before mentioned folders

I understand this: 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms366723.aspx

is the reason of all trouble, however I do not understand why editing the path variable to include the correct path containing the Dll's doesn't solve anything.

Last useful post about this issue was in 2008, however no fool-proof solution has ben offered yet, so all the help is much appreciated!

Comment: Are the DLL's registered on the Development machines? i.e via regsvr32
Is the application pool set to run in 32BIT mode?

Comment: DLL's have not ben registered on the development machines (so the situation is the same on development and webserver), and the application pool is set to allow 32bit apps (IIS7)

Comment: if you use Depends on opencv_core240.dll are all the dlls listed available on the web server?

Comment: Depends complains about not finding: MSVCP100.dll
MSVCR100.dll, however after installing the VS2010 redist package (x86) http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&FamilyID=a7b7a05e-6de6-4d3a-a423-37bf0912db84 - still nothing

Comment: Unfortunately not, we ended up removing any reference to this library and using a different approach for this altogether.

Comment: Such a shame; EMGUCV+OpenCV are great packages, but plagued by DLL-hell. Why can they not provide a coherent set of DLLs, in one single folder, that all work togehter?

Answer (score 2):

Make sure tbb.dll is also in the path, as opencv_core240.dll has a dependency on this. You can find tbb.dll under opencv/build/common/tbb.

Comment: Thank you, I had the same problem with OpenCvSharp 2.4 (instead of Emgu, and on a local machine) and this solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 1):

In my case "npp32_xx_x.dll" (xx_x is version no, 32 is the 32bit architecture) solved the problem.
So you can try putting this dll to your projects out put folder for win apps and equivalent folder in web apps.
The dll is Nvidia Cuda NPP Library.

Answer (score 0):

From your error description and checks you already performed, it seems like that you have not installed MSVCRT.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, however I checked and MSVCRT is installed on the webserver.

Comment: Create an x86 folder inside your bin folder and try to copy opencv dlls such as opencv_core240.dll and the others there.That could fix module not found error.

Comment: Should've mentioned that earlier - but I tried that as well, without any luck unfortunatly

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem few days back, I tried everything in my knowledge, but nothing helped to fix the issue. EmguCV works fine in my local 64bit Windows 8 pc but the server (Windows Web Server 64bit).

But the problem was fixed after i did some truly random stuffs as follows:
The server has Visual C++ 2008 Runtime previously installed, but again

1. i installed `Visual C++ 2010 x86`.
2. **Repaired** `Visual C++ 2008 x86 Runtime installation`

and that fixed the problem. I can't explain how this happened, but i'm happy that the problem solved after two days of random experiment.

Answer (score 0):

To solve this problem put `nvcuda.dll` in `/bin` folder on web server. Be sure `nvcuda.dll` must be **x86 Architecture** is the same as the server, or x64 if web server has **x64 Architecture**.

In future see other dependences in Dependence Walker [`http://www.dependencywalker.com/`](http://www.dependencywalker.com/)and put this dll's with parent libraries.