# Type initialization exception

Tags: c#, .net, opencv, constructor, emgucv

I created imageHolder class:

```
public class ImageHolder : Image<Bgr, Byte>
{   
    private String imagePath;

    public ImageHolder(String path):base(path)
    {
       this.imagePath = path;                     
    }   
    public String imgPathProperty
    {
        get
        { return imagePath; }
        set
        { imagePath = value; }
    }
}
```

I create instance of the class and initialize it,like this:

```
private ImageHolder originalImageHolder;
originalImageHolder = new ImageHolder(openFileDialog.FileName);
```

In runtime i get this exception:

**The type initializer for 'Emgu.CV.CvInvoke' threw an exception.**

[image]

Here is Solution Explorer window:

[image]

Any idea why i get this exception and how can i fix it?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Looks like it can't find opencv_core240.dll; does that need to be in the same folder?

Comment: not exactly a duplicate of this (since there was no accepted answer)but maybe some of the information on [this other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10930610/opencv-unmanaged-dlls-not-found-asp-net) and answers may work for you

Comment: To reiterate and expand on what @zimdanen said, the InnerException text states that it was unable to load the DLL zimdanen mentions. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2066180/the-specified-module-could-not-be-found-0x8007007e for an explanation.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The [TypeInitializationException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.typeinitializationexception.aspx)  (the exception that you are seeing) is thrown whenever a static constructor throws an exception, or whenever you attempt to access a class where the static constructor threw an exception - its [InnerException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.exception.innerexception.aspx) property is the property that contains the detail of the exception that was actualy thrown - this is the exception that you need to investigate.

In this case from your screenshot the problem appears to be that the DLL "opencv_core240.dll" could not be found.  This could be for a number of reasons

- The DLL couldn't be found
- One of the dependencies of the DLL could not be found
- The DLL was in the incorrect image format (32 bit as opposed to 64 bit)

I'd suggest that you take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10930610/opencv-unmanaged-dlls-not-found-asp-net) to see if any of the suggestions on there help you.

Answer (score 2):

[image: VS Project Properties Page]

Checking this field did the trick for me. Under **Project**→ Properties→ Build (Main/Startup project)

Comment: Yes - this fixed the issue for me too. Turns out the DLL my project requires can only be run in 32 bit! D'oh!

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem by reinstalling  [MSVCRT 9.0 SP1 x86](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8328)