# Saving array of bitmaps to separate files with C#

Tags: c#, arrays, bitmap, save, typeinitializeexception

I'm stuck at saving an array of `System.Drawing.Bitmap` type, each bitmap to separate file. 
I have an array "survey". This array stores several Lists of double type.
For each List i want to create a bitmap and then save it as a bmp file.
The **line** `raport[i].Save(Path.Combine(myfilepath, nets[i] + ".bmp"));` returns **TypeInitializationException** - and i **don't know why**.
The piece `nets[i]` is a dictionary (int, string) with expected file names.

```
public void save_results()
    {
        System.Drawing.Bitmap[] raport = new System.Drawing.Bitmap[survey.Length];

        for (int i = 0; i < survey.Length; i++)
        {
            raport[i] = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(survey[i].Count, 1000);

            for (int x = 0; x < survey[i].Count; x++)
                for (int y = 0; y < 1000; y++)
                    raport[i].SetPixel(x, y, Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 255));

            for (int x = 0; x < survey[i].Count; x++)
                raport[i].SetPixel(x, (int)(1000 - Math.Floor(survey[i][x] * 1000) >= 1000 ? 999 : 1000 - Math.Floor(survey[i][x] * 1000)), Color.FromArgb(0, 0, 0));

    raport[i].Save(Path.Combine(myfilepath, nets[i] + ".bmp"));
        }
    }
```

Comment: You need to view the InnerException of the TypeInitializationException to get more information. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12425381/5095502).

Comment: Under the hood Bitmap.Save calls for particular codec (see System.Drawing.ImageFormat). I think the issue is with codec initialization. You can try to specify ImageFormat explicitly. Also, stacktrace  would be helpful.

Comment: I once had a similar issue saving multiple files at once and i think it was because the save was not synchronous. I don't know if this is the case. Someone can confirm?
I think I wasn't coding in c#, but I guess the file saving might be handled similarly. Saving a file might take a relatively long time, but this affects only the HDD, so the rest of the program could go on. It makes sense to me if it is async in c# too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, the problem was associated with the variable "myfilepath".
The variable was 'compiled' from few file paths - and all of those strings should have been `static`:

```
    public static string mydoc= Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);
    public static string myfilepath_p = Path.Combine(mydoc, "Demeter");
    public static string myfilepath= Path.Combine(myfilepath_p, "regresja_liniowa");
```

Originally, only the 'final' variable used in the cited code was `static`, what caused an error.

Rest of the code worked fine.