# TypeInitializationException thrown by pocketsphinx c# wrapper

Tags: c#, pocketsphinx

I am creating a sample of PocketSphinx using the steps given here https://github.com/cmusphinx/pocketsphinx/

I have generated Csharp classes defined in their procedure which is successfull. The problem i am facing is, I have integrated those classes and the test.cs written by them. But I am getting error while running that class.

[Error Image Please refer for detail](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rs2j5.png)

It will be great if anyone can help me out with this.
Thanks

Comment: You miss the proper dll

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12425199/type-initialization-exception

Comment: It gives me these output files without any error after MakeFile.
http://prntscr.com/hz0s7u

Comment: Proper build process depends on your OS and IDE