# What does "No suitable directory found to load unmanaged modules" mean in EMGU?

Tags: c#, opencv, emgucv

I'm an EMGU/CV noob using using EMGU3.0 (emgucv-windows-universal 3.0.0.2157), Visual Studio 2013, and a target platform of "Any CPU". I'm trying the C# "hello world" app at http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Hello_World_in_CSharp#Hello_World_-_Version_2 which looks like this:

```
using Emgu.CV;
using Emgu.CV.CvEnum;
using Emgu.CV.Structure;
using Emgu.CV.UI;
using System.Drawing;

...

//Create a 3 channel image of 400x200
using (Mat img = new Mat(200, 400, DepthType.Cv8U, 3)) 
{
   img.SetTo(new Bgr(255, 0, 0).MCvScalar); // set it to Blue color

   //Draw "Hello, world." on the image using the specific font
   CvInvoke.PutText(
      img, 
      "Hello, world", 
      new System.Drawing.Point(10, 80), 
      FontFace.HersheyComplex, 
      1.0, 
      new Bgr(0, 255, 0).MCvScalar);

   //Show the image using ImageViewer from Emgu.CV.UI
   ImageViewer.Show(img, "Test Window");

}
```

It builds OK. But when I ran it I got "The type initializer for 'Emgu.CV.MatInvoke' threw an exception." . . . at the line . . .

```
using (Mat img = new Mat(200, 400, DepthType.Cv8U, 3))
```

Also, in the output window there's another clue. Just before the exception there's a message about unmanaged modules . . .

> ```
> No suitable directory found to load unmanaged modules
>
> A first chance exception of type 'System.TypeInitializationException'
> occurred in Emgu.CV.dll
> ```

Any idea what's happening here or how to debug it?

**Note:** There's a question on SO [OpenCV Unmanaged DLLs not found asp.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10930610/opencv-unmanaged-dlls-not-found-asp-net) that involves a different error message - "System.DllNotFoundException" under different circumstances, (it also has no accepted answers).   That error message is produced by the system but I think the one I'm getting is produced by EMGU itself.   But if any ENGU experts see how that applies to mine I'd appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

The Emgu cannot find the OpenCV dlls. 
Simplest solution :

- Go to your Emgu installation , the **bin** folder
- Find inside the folders **x86** and **x64**
- Copy these folders to the **bin\Debug** **bin\Release**  folder of your project.
- Try again.